# Unable to start mongo kafka connect

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I’m able to start kafka connect without mongo source connector. But when I try to start with source connector as well, I get following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/Schema
```

my worker properties look like:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/kafka/3.6.1/connectorLib
```

my mongo source connector properties look like:

```
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/changeStream?replicaSet=rs0
database=changeStream
collection=author

output.format.key=json
output.format.value=json

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false

value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

pipeline=[{"$match": {"operationType": "insert"}}, {"$project": { "fullDocument._id": 0} } ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I start kafka connect like:

`bin/connect-standalone connectorConfig/demoMongoConfig/worker.properties connectorConfig/demoMongoConfig/source.properties`

I have place mongo kafka connector lib within `mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.11.2` directory, which I have already mentioned in worker properties' `plugin.path` key.

How to resolve this?